# Angular Material CDK Overlay scroll block not working when in nav sidebar

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I am adding a CDK overlay to a mat-sidenav.  I would like to block scrolling on the mat-sidenav when the overlay is open.

I create overlay with scrolling blocked:

```
const overlayConfig = new OverlayConfig({
  scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.block(),
});

const overlayRef = this.overlay.create(overlayConfig);
```

I am not doing anything special with the mat-sidenav, as its scrollable by default.

Here is a stackblitz showing the problem.  You should be able to scroll the side-nav, then open and overlay and notice that the sidenav is still scrollable

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z68qqg

[image]

Comment: looking at the block scroll strategy code https://github.com/angular/components/blob/598db096e668aa7e9debd56eedfd127b7a55e371/src/cdk/overlay/scroll/block-scroll-strategy.ts#L37 it seams like this strategy blocks scrolling only of the body. What you need is a future request you may log at angular components

Comment: @wnvko Ok, bummer. I tried the reposition strategy with no luck as well. Assuming something similar there too?

Comment: have you checked scroll Strategies? https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview#scroll-strategies/  it seems BlockScrollStrategy is specifically for that

Comment: @lostintranslation did you manage to solve this problem, i'm facing the same problem and I tried with the `cdk-scrollable` directive but it didn't help me much. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You have to add cdk-scrollable directive on scrollable container, as described in this issue
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/6157

Answer (score 0):

You have to add cdkScrollable attribute to the scrolling element. Then applying a scrolling strategy would work. For your case, you can use a close strategy to close the popover on the scroll.